# After updating a page in the browser dynamically inserted page content disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom

I develop an HTML5 webapp with JQM and what I would like to achieve is that after the page with the dynamically added page content (there is a button on the previous page which executes a JS function after it has been clicked and this script generates the content) is refreshed this content does not disappear but stays.

If this is not possible what event should I bind the script to which will generate the content again and put it into this page?

Comment: Please do not swear in your questions.

Comment: I am sorry! It won't happen again.

Answer (score 2):

When the page refreshes, any client-side context is *gone* at that point.  Consider the page itself and all of the JavaScript therein as an application in and of itself.  Refreshing the page is tantamount to closing and re-opening the application.

Given that, any context or state which has been created in that page which needs to be available the next time the page is loaded will need to be persisted somewhere.  There are a number of places to do this.  For example:

- Server-side code
- Cookies
- Local storage

Given that you're primarily talking about HTML5 and JavaScript for your development, local storage is probably your best bet in this scenario.  There's [a handy guide here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) that can get you started, though a quick Google search for "HTML5 Local Storage" reveals considerably more.  Essentially what you need to do is:

- Define some data which represents the state that you wish to save between page loads
- Write that data to local storage any time that state changes
- Read that data from local storage any time the page loads (since you specifically asked for an event, the document's "ready" event is probably what you want here just like most other jQuery code) and restore the state of the page from that data

Comment: Thank you so so much, David! This is a very helpful answer.

Comment: Would the document's "ready" event also work for a single page app? I navigate to the pages via #, e. g. file:///C/exampleproject/index.html#page1

Comment: @busuzima: Possibly, tough to say without seeing the context.  The document's ready event is when the structure of the document is complete and available, so any event *before* that would need to be carefully thought out as you could run into problems while the document continues to build.  If, for some aspects of the interface, you need to wait until specific referenced content is also loaded (such as images), then a later event might work better.  document.ready is a good place to start, though.

Comment: One more thing I would to learn. After I click the button and navigate to the page with the generated content it is there and everything is fine, but after I hit the browsers "back" button and then click the button again, I of course move to the page I want to and the content appears twice. I read that the data is stored in the memory but how can I prevent generating the same content multiple times? Should I use "if" statements?

Comment: @busuzima: That I can't answer without a lot more context and code to reproduce the problem, since there are lots of things which could factor into it.  It sounds like it should be its own Stack Overflow question at that point.